# Peak curvature in Scipy spline

Tags: python, scipy

How can I find the peak curvature of a spline fitted using scipy? (Actually, peak second differential would be enough)

I have calculated the `tck` values as follows, using my 1d `xs` and `ys` vectors:

```
tck = splrep(xs, ys, s=0)
```

I know I can evaluate the second differential at any `x` of my choice:

```
ddy = splev([x], tck, 2)
```

So I could loop over many values of `x`, calculate the curvature and take the maximum. But I would prefer to interpret the values in `tck` to get the coefficients of the individual cubic functions, and thus calculate the peak curvature directly. However, `tck` appears rather opaque - how can I extract the cubic function coefficients from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `der` keyword argument on `splev` function:

```
ddy = splev(X, tck, der=2)
```

and preferrably don't loop over many values of `x`, instead make a Nx1 array `X` containing every value you want to evaluate, so as to get back an array of values instead of individual values you'll have to put in a sequence anyway.

Also, it is extremely adviseable to PLOT your results as a way to debug it. If plots make sense, things are most likely working (and, if not, they surely are NOT working) as you expect.

EDIT: in case the interpolation using X gives just an approximate value and you want the TRUE maximum, you can use parabolic interpolation of the three points that define the maximum (the local interpolated maximum and its neighbors), considering the spline is locally smooth:

```
def parabolic_interpolation(p1, p2, p3):
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    x3, y3 = p3

    denom = (x1-x2)*(x1-x3)*(x2-x3);
    a = (x3*(y2-y1)+x2*(y1-y3)+x1*(y3-y2))/denom
    b = (x3*x3*(y1-y2)+x2*x2*(y3-y1)+x1*x1*(y2-y3))/denom
    c = (x2*x3*(x2-x3)*y1+x3*x1*(x3-x1)*y2+x1*x2*(x1-x2)*y3)/denom

    xv = -b/(2*a)
    yv = c-b**2/(4*a)

    return (xv, yv)  # coordinates of the vertex
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I agree that would be a better way to evaluate the derivative at a large number of values, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I want to find the maximum based directly on the cubic coefficients.

Comment: Just to understand what you want to do: since the spline is defined piecewise, you want to take the coefficient of each spline segment and calculate its vertex, then select the maximum of those vertices? I'm not sure they work that way, since they are parametric (`x,y = f(p)`) instead of cartesian (`x = f(y)`)

Comment: If you don't want to create a huge array of candidate points, but want to find the ACTUAL peak for each local maximum (instead of an aproximate value when the actual peak is between two interpolated points), you can follow two approaches: 1) you interpolate a regular range of values where you know there is a maximum, or some maximums. Then you refine this interpolation iteratively around the desired points, using bisection or Newton-Raphson-like methods; 2) you find the three points around a maximum, then perform parabolic interpolation.

Comment: Ah, I was being dim. Of course I can evaluate the second differential at each of my x input values - the spline is cubic so I know the second differential will vary linearly between my x points. Thanks.

Comment: @AaronLockey I think it's worth to mention that a cubic spline is not quite like a cubic polynomial, although your rationale of linear second derivative would be a good aproximation, I think.